# Retrieve date from datetime column in polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Currently when I try to retrieve date from a polars datetime column, I have to write sth. similar to:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'time': [dt.datetime.now()]
})


df = df.select([
    pl.col("*"),
    pl.col("time").apply(lambda x: x.date()).alias("date")
])
```

Is there a different way, something closer to:

```py
pl.col("time").dt.date().alias("date")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can cast a `Datetime` column to a `Date` column:

```py
import datetime
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'time': [datetime.datetime.now()]
})

df.with_column(
    pl.col("time").cast(pl.Date)
)
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ time       │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 2022-08-02 │
└────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

Since polars version 0.16.15 (released just a few days ago). The code in your question is actually valid.

```
pl.col("time").dt.date().alias("date")
```

[This is the diff](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7735) that made it possible. And it works both on `pl.Series` and `pl.Expr` (used in lazy data frames).

Comment: what is stackoverflows procedure to update the question then, do I just add an edit on top?

Comment: I don't think you need to change anything :)